# How can i get my form fields to auto update as a user types?

Tags: javascript, forms, sum, field

Hi i have a form with several inputs/fields.  I'm using the script below to find the sum of the values entered into theses fields as opposed to updating the sum value field after a user leaves the field input like when a user clicks outside a field input box.  How can I get this script to auto update the field the sum shows in as the user types in the value.

```
<script>
var $form = $('#contactForm'),
    $summands = $form.find('.sum1'),
    $sumDisplay = $('#itmttl');

$form.delegate('.sum1', 'change', function ()
{
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function ()
    {
        var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });

    $sumDisplay.val(sum);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is this script after your elements that you are trying to reference? If not you will need to use a onload callback ie `$(document).ready` or `window.onload`

Comment: yes is after elements im referencing

Comment: if you want it to change as they type use the keyup event

Comment: how would I go about doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `input` event which is triggerd for any input.
It is also effective for the new `HTML5` input `number` that uses spinners.

```
$('.num1').on("input",function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $.each($summands, function(){
        var n = $(this).val();
        sum = isNaN(n) || n == '' ? sum : sum+parseFloat(n); 
    });
    $('#sum').text(sum);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6n4kugbp/

Comment: You can still use jQuery: `$('#input-id').val(sum)`